# mercurial_keyring extension for hg - How can I change the keyring password?

Tags: python, mercurial, dvcs, mercurial-extension

I recently installed mercurial on my ubuntu server (running Ubuntu Server 11.10) and with it the oh so useful mercurial_keyring extension. In setting things up, I mistakenly entered a keyring password that I do not like...

This bothers me a bit, because now every operation with my remote repository asks me for this password...

Is there a way to change the keyring password easily?

```
mysuperusername@mysuperserver:/var/www/...$ hg push
pushing to https://...@bitbucket.org/.../...
Please input your password for the keyring
Password:
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the keyring password is managed by the password store and not the extension directly. So you will have to change that in your keystore.

Since your on Ubuntu, I'm supposing that you use the default keyring, a way to change the password can be found here : https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-keyring-password-prompt/

If you're using another keyring, you should provide us with more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I forgot to mention that I am on Ubuntu Server, so none of the nice GUI menus apply :-(. I will update my question as well.

Comment: @lfboulanger I'm not familiar with the Ubuntu Server application stack since I'm a Debian guy myself. Do you know what is the keyring application used ?